# Error uploading blob to Azure Storage using REST - Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a blob to azure storage account using REST API.

As read in many docs, I am first creating the file:

```
$headers = @{
   'x-ms-blob-type' = 'BlockBlob'
}
```

Invoking PUT operation to the SAS URI (directly copied from Azure portal)

```
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/pdf/agb_megasim.pdf?sp=rac&st=2021-06-30T09:52:08Z&se=2021-07-31T17:52:08Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=uhuEFp%2Bl1MJO%2B8dfsUYkfpegPK9KeYPOPsN08govKGg%3D
```

Next, I am sending (PUT) a byte stream to the url. The SAS url is modified to add comp=range

```
$headers = @{
    "x-ms-version" = "2015-02-21"
    "x-ms-range"   = "bytes=0-86751"
    "x-ms-date"    = "7/5/2021 4:55:47 PM"
    "x-ms-write"   = "update"
    'x-ms-blob-type' = 'BlockBlob' 
}
```

```
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/pdf/agb_megasim.pdf?**comp=range**&sp=rac&st=2021-06-30T09:52:08Z&se=2021-07-31T17:52:08Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=uhuEFp%2Bl1MJO%2B8dfsUYkfpegPK9KeYPOPsN08govKGg%3D
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:bd905701-d01e-0036-6fbc-71bbbf000000
Time:2021-07-05T16:42:26.9354872Z</Message>
</Error>
```

This seems to be the procedure from various documents I tried, but doesnt work for me!
I tried using Powershell and postman.

**Any idea which parameter is causing the issue?**

Also, this is how i intend to pass the file contents:
Reading the file

```
$fileContentBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
```

Not sure, if encoding is required,

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're performing [`Put Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) operation and trying to create a `Block Blob`, you need not specify `comp=range` parameter in your query string. Please try your operation by removing that.

Furthermore, the only header you need to provide in your request is `x-ms-blob-type`. You can remove all other headers from your request.

Comment: Thanks, the doc said many of these were required. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob
It was a mistake trying to follow steps used for azure files :(

I have tried this as just one PUT operation and it works!

Comment: `the doc said many of these were required` - They are required when you're authorizing your requests using shared key authorization (i.e. using account key). Since you're using a shared access signature, most of these headers are not required.